# Работа с GPS координатами

Tags: gps, php, mysql

Есть таблица в MySQL с множеством записей GPS координат в виде *latitude* и *longitude*.

**Задача** – разбить всю карту мира на множество частей (сетка с определенным шагом) и 
иметь потом возможность определить, к какой клетке (координаты ее углов) относится какая-нибудь GPS точка. Например:

```
$activeCellCoordinates = cellForCoordinates({10.055402736564236, 38.1005859375});
```

Нужно будет потом записать в базу координаты углов каждой такой клетки (если какие-нибудь из GPS точек в нее попадут, или будут находиться рядом с краями), но речь уже не об этом.

[image: img]

Собственно, как это более-менее оптимально реализовать на *php*? Как мы знаем, границы *latitude*: -90 и 90, а *longitude*: 180 и -180. И взять, к примеру, шаг в 0.01 – это уже 648 000 000 клеток :(

Спасибо, заранее!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А какая разница сколько клеток? Рассмотрим простой случай: ось X, максимальное значение 180, разделена на 100 отрезков. Нужно найти координаты отрезка, в который попадает точка с `x=10.0554`. В x содержится `ceil(x/(180/100))` целых отрезков, левая координата последнего отрезка будет равна `floor(x/(180/100))*(180/100)`, правая `ceil(x/(180/100))*(180/100)`

Для оси Y, соответственно, считаем по коэффициенту `90/100`.

Таким образом, для вашей точки по обеим осям получаем: x1=9.000, x2=10.8000, y1=37.8000, y2=38.7000 (округлил до 4 знаков).

Может где-то налажал с циферками, но принцип такой, +добавляем ещё обработку отрицательных координат, +оптимизируем арифметику.

P.S. Да, и не имеет смысла заносить в базу координаты клеток заранее. Клеток, в которых содержатся объекты, будет на порядки меньше. Получили точку, посчитали координаты клетки. Есть такая в базе - создали связь "точка-клетка", нет - занесли клетку и создали связь. Естественно, каждая клетка должна быть в базе в одном экземпляре, а не для каждой точки своя копия.

Comment: Да уж, мое высчитывание клеток заранее, это был совсем глупый подход. Подсчеты надо делать по факту обращения. Осталось теперь только вашу формулу правильно применить.
А за то, что за меня все посчитали – отдельное спасибо. Пойду разбираться.
По поводу занесения в базу, да, все клево, проблема у меня именно с координатами.

Comment: Кстати, подумалось: для поиска квадрата в базе не обязательно сравнивать все 4 координаты. Можно при создании записи вычислять некую функцию от них, которая была бы уникальна для каждого квадрата. Например, ту же md5 от координат. Или какую-то ещё, лишь бы точность вычислений её не корёжила. Тогда поиск может быть быстрей.

Comment: Или 2 координаты сравнивать вместо 4 - центр квадрата... Эк меня прорвало :)