# Как разбить карту на определенные сектора?

Tags: геолокация

Здравствуйте.

Каким образом можно разбить карту мира или определенную ее часть (например, город) на сектора? Допустим, квадраты по 1 км. Как с помощью latitude и longitude, полученных с мобильного телефона, определить к какому квадрату они принадлежат?

Answer (score 1):

В 1 градусе широты содержится 40000/360 километров.
"Размер" градуса долготы зависит от широты: (40000/360)*cos(широта). Про разбиение по кординатам см. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/210608/php-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-gps-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), разбивка по километрам делается аналогично.